# Compiling x264 for iOS 7

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, ffmpeg, clang, x264

I'm getting error on compiling x264 for iOS.

I have Xcode Version 5.0 (5A1413) with Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.75) (based on LLVM 3.3svn). I'm compiling x264-snapshot-20130925-2245.

Config:

```
CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang ./configure \
--host=arm-apple-darwin \
--sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk \
--prefix=armv7 \
--extra-cflags='-arch armv7' \
--extra-ldflags="-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/lib/system -arch armv7" \
--enable-pic \
--enable-static
```

Getting error:

```
common/arm/cpu-a.S:29:7: error: unknown token in expression
.align
      ^
common/arm/cpu-a.S:139:5: error: instruction 'suble' can not set flags, but 's' suffix specified
    subles ip, ip, #1
    ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the only solution seems to be `--disable-asm`.

Answer (score 5):

The relevant change in the Xcode 5 toolchain is that the LLVM compiler now defaults to using the built-in assembler, and the built-in assembler requires more strict adherence to the ARM Unified Assembly Language.

There are two ways to get it to compile with the Xcode 5 toolchain:

1. Give clang the flag -no-integrated-as.  Adding it to --extra-cflags ought to work.  (The flag worked for me compiling individual files but I never worked it into configure.)  Consider this a workaround.
2. Fix the assembly source code in x264's common/arm subdirectory.  This is pretty easy actually, and it's what I did.  This is the right fix.  BTW, I'm about to submit a patch to x264 with these changes.

The assembler emits many errors and they fall into four categories:

- In cpu-a.S, the ".align" directive should be ".align 2".  (Apparently it used to default to 2, now the 2 must be explicit.)
- Several subles and sublts instructions in multiple files.  These are variants of "sub" (subtract), followed by a condition (2 characters) and the "s" suffix.  Now the "s" has to precede the condition.  Thus "subles" => "subsle" and "sublts" => "subslt".
- A fair number of ldrd instructions in various files.  This instruction means "load register, double (from memory)".  It loads 2 32-bit words from memory into registers.  It used to be OK to name only the first register; now both need to be named.  They're always adjacent.  So "ldrd r2, whatever" needs to become "ldrd r2, r3, whatever".  "ldrd r6, something" becomes "ldrd r6, r7, something".  Etc.
- In pixel-a.S, there's an instruction "vmov.32 r0, r1, d0".  This is incorrect.  vmov.32 means move a 32-bit quantity, yet the arguments say to move d0 (64 bits) into r0 and r1.  Apparently the old compiler took the ".32" part as a hint.  I believe it should be "vmov r0, r1, d0" and that change works for me - but I don't have absolute proof that is the correct instruction.

Many thanks to gparker on the Apple Developer Forum!  I could not have figured this out without his/her help.  [Link to forum discussion, Apple ID required.](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/212660?tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

I think disabling assembler optimizations is a bad solution.

After a long research I've found the root of the problem: clang during assembler compilation uses ASFLAGS not CFLAGS, so adding --extra-asflags="-arch armv7" solves the problem

```
./configure \
--host=arm-apple-darwin \
--sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk \
--prefix=armv7 \
--extra-cflags="-arch armv7" \
--extra-asflags="-arch armv7" \
--extra-ldflags="-arch armv7" \
--enable-pic \
--enable-static
```

NOTE: For bitcode support just add `-fembed-bitcode` to all extra flags parameters