# Error during cross compilation on MacOSX for iOS

Tags: ios, assembly, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to crossbuild X264 opensource library (configure/make/make install) for iOS. I've built a script to set all the environment variable (compiler paths, sdk paths etc) and it works on my iPad with `--disable-asm` option.

Now, i would like to use the lib with the asm support, but I receive this error from assembler:

```
FATAL:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/../libexec/as/arm/as: I don't understand 'D' flag!
```

I've tried to remove from `configure` script in the `$ASFLAGS` variable the "-D" flags, perhaps it is wrong but i read on the `GNU as` that that flag should be ignored; after that it hangs with the same error on the `i` flag...

Can somebody help me? is it better to use the REAL `GNU as` instead that provided with Xcode?

Thanks in advice

Comment: thanks for the reply! there were no config bug, but i'm not sure. surely the compilation without asm optimization (--disable-asm, only plain C) did work. but it seems looks like some error with xcode embedded assembler (i mean when it tries to assembly ARM code directly, *.S files, the optimization you mentioned), it doesn't accept gnu flags. I don't understand how to translate GNU AS flags into xcode flags (there are only inclusion directive and loop alignment offset as i read in the scripts)

Comment: The error is when it tries to build an assembler file?  I think you need to give more context.  Can you get a minimal command line and source file?  Ie, trim things down and still get this error.  Does it build with empty source?  Assembler sections have **flags** and maybe the 'D' flag is not a command line one.  Although you seem to say that editing the command line changes the error message. See: [compiling x264](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027157/compiling-x264-for-ios-7)

Comment: yes, as soon as possibile i will post a trim of the output with the error of the assembler. and yes, the error is when it tries to build an ASM file (.S). I've changed (testing porpouse) the option passed to AS in the `configure` script and the error changes (removed D flags, it refuses the I flags with the same message)

Comment: this is the error `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/as -DPREFIX -DPIC -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -Wall -I. -I. -std=gnu99 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -c -DSTACK_ALIGNMENT=16 -DPIC -DHIGH_BIT_DEPTH=0 -DBIT_DEPTH=8 -o common/arm/cpu-a.o common/arm/cpu-a.S
FATAL:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/../libexec/as/arm/as: I don't understand 'D' flag!
make: *** [common/arm/cpu-a.o] Error 1`

Comment: if I modify the `configure` script in order to remove the flags passed to AS (many of them are inherited from C flags) the error change to `I don't understand 'i' flag!`